# React Native Xcode Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group - _RCT.. problem

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I try to get build via xcode in my application with react native, I get error like below. I have tried many solutions via xcode, but I can't find out why the problem occurred. Can you help me with this?

[image: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)]

Xcode Version: 11.3 (11C29)
React Native Version : 0.61.5

Comment: Have you tried `pod install` inside the ios folder?

Comment: I solved it. The test file failed because I did not export the class while trying to run it. I deleted the target of the test file and the error disappeared.